# How do I access JavaScript built-ins in Typings when there are name conflicts?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm working on updating Paper.js Typings found at the following GitHub repo:

[github.com/clark-stevenson/paper.d.ts](https://github.com/clark-stevenson/paper.d.ts/blob/master/paper.d.ts)

Paper.js has their own MouseEvent class, MouseEvent. It doesn't extend JavaScript's MouseEvent, it's a wrapper around it with the same name. And that's the entire problem. How do I reference JavaScript's built-in MouseEvent when there is a class with the same name?

Since I never instantiate a Paper.js Mouse Event myself, my current workaround is renaming it to PaperMouseEvent:

```
export class PaperMouseEvent extends Event {
    constructor(type:string, event:MouseEvent, point:Point, target:Item, delta:Point)

    /**
     * JavaScript's mouse event
     */
    event:MouseEvent;
}
```

Is there a way to do this properly, or this a common workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then you simply need to do:

```
declare module "paper" {
    class MouseEvent extends Event {
        constructor(type:string, event:MouseEvent, point:Point, target:Item, delta:Point);
        event: MouseEvent;
    }
}
```

---

#### Edit

You can try to use a type alias to "save reference" to the built-in `MouseEvent`:

```
type NativeMouseEvent = MouseEvent;

declare module "paper" {
    class MouseEvent extends Event {
        constructor(type:string, event:MouseEvent, point:Point, target:Item, delta:Point);
        event: NativeMouseEvent;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Trying to access the original JavaScript event properties(pageX, offsetX, altKey, etc.) causes TSC to throw an error like this: 

Property 'offsetX' does not exist on type 'MouseEvent'.

Comment: Oh. I understand the problem now. Check my revised answer